Updating a Variable in Azure pipeline
I have a CI/CD pipeline on Azure. I have set up a .yaml file and a variable called SerialNumber, set to 000000 directly in the Azure interface (not in the .yaml). I want it to be used inside of the pipeline and the updated, adding 1 on every iteration.
The .yaml looks like this:
variables:
  myPipelineVariable: $[variables.SerialNumber]

jobs:

- job: Update_Variable
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: "task1"
    displayName: this is task1
    inputs:

      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "the value of the variable is : $(myPipelineVariable)"
        $newValue = [int]$(myPipelineVariable) + 1
        $formattedValue = "{0:D6}" -f $newValue  # Format the number with leading zeros
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myPipelineVariable;isOutput=true]$formattedValue"
    enabled: true

the problem is if i save and run the pipeline the number in the Azure interface then doesn't change, and the next time starts from 000000 again. I also tried inserting another job in the .yaml:
- job: Show_Variable
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: "task2"
    displayName: this is task2
    inputs:

      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "the new value of the variable is : $(myPipelineVariable)"
    enabled: true

but it prints: 000000
how can i handle this operation to update the value of the variable inside of Azure, so that every build that i trigger uses it and then adds one to the number automatically?

You cannot change variable that way. It will be only for execution and won't be persisted.
But the thing which you are looking for is a counter expression

You can create a counter that is automatically incremented by one in each execution of your pipeline. When you define a counter, you provide a prefix and a seed. Here is an example that demonstrates this.

variables:
  major: 1
  # define minor as a counter with the prefix as variable major, and seed as 100.
  minor: $[counter(variables['major'], 100)]

steps:
- bash: echo $(minor)

Take a look on the documentation here

i see it works, even though I have had difficulty in finding a way to reset the counter when I want. It is my understanding that you need to change the value of the seed (major) in order to reset minor. Another thing I am having difficulty with is formatting the output. it seems like anything like echo $(format('{0:000000}', minor) or variants is not working.I would like to pass this value formatted as six characters

I would suggest you use the variable group to store the variable SerialNumber. Then, we can use the REST API Variablegroups - Update to update the value in the pipeline.
My Steps:

Create a variable group with Variable SerialNumber= 000000.


Give your build service account the Administrator role in security setting of the variable group.


The following is my test sample yaml:


trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

variables:
- group: variable group 0418
- name: VariableGroupName
  value: 'variable group 0418'
jobs:
- job: Update_Variable
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    env:
      MY_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "The value of the SerialNumber is : $(SerialNumber)"
        echo "Updating the SerialNumber in Variable Group..."

        $newValue = [int]$(SerialNumber) + 1
        $formattedValue = "{0:D6}" -f $newValue
        
        $orgname="your org name"
        $projectname = "your project name"
        $variableGroupId = 14  # Replace with your actual variable group ID
        
        $url = "https://dev.azure.com/$orgname/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/$($variableGroupId)?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
        
        $body = @"
        {
            "name": "$(VariableGroupName)",
            "providerData": null,
            "type": "Vsts",
            "variables": {
                "SerialNumber": {
                    "isSecret": false,
                    "value": "$formattedValue"
                }
            },
            "variableGroupProjectReferences": [
                {
                    "name": "$(VariableGroupName)",
                    "projectReference": {
                        "id": "",
                        "name": "$projectname"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        "@
        
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $body -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{
          "Authorization" = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"
        }
        $response | ConvertTO-Json

- job: Show_Variable
  dependsOn: Update_Variable
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: "task2"
    displayName: this is task2
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "the new SerialNumber is : $(SerialNumber)"
    enabled: true


Test result





Every time you run the pipeline, the value of SerialNumber will +1 and be stored in the Variable group.


Check this doc about variables in different jobs: Use outputs in a different job. Add a variable definition to the second job:
- job: Show_Variable
  timeoutInMinutes: 0
  variables:
    # map the output variable from A into this job
    myPipelineVariable: $[ dependencies.Update_Variable.outputs['task1.myPipelineVariable'] ]
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    name: "task2"
    displayName: this is task2
    inputs:

      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        echo "the new value of the variable is : $(myPipelineVariable)"
    enabled: true

